# Counting unique values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, unique

I have a list that looks like this:

```
Location   ID
______________
Boston     12
Boston     12
Boston     12
Boston     57
Boston     99
Chicago    12
Chicago    13
...
```

For each Location I want to count up the number of unique IDs. Boston would have 3 and Chicago would have 2 for example.

I can use Advanced filter by unique records but I want to know how to do this using an Excel formula.

Comment: Do you know all the locations you will have?

Comment: @pnuts Possibly, why? Does that work, too?

Comment: @Jorvik77 Yes. I have a list of unique locations and I'm using that list to feed into the formula to do the counting.

Comment: @pnuts If I use PivotTable it doesn't count unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$8=D2,1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,D2)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: How did you get your Excel to look dark gray like that?

Comment: Its under Account under the File tab.

Comment: To add to this. If you didn't know the locations you could use this code in Column D2 and drag it down to get your unique list of cities =INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$8),0,0),0))